# IOS swift radar chart view y-axis max and min value doesn't work on plot

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I tried to implement an iOS radar chart view based on Daniel Gindi's library.

When I try to set the value of y-axis, it doesn't work as the max is still  a little too high. And if I don't set it, which is the auto setting based on the data, it will change so it is not the problem of auto setting.

I looked through other solutions and most of them are very outdated.

Here is the code I am using:

```
let yAxis = chartView.yAxis
yAxis.labelFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 9, weight: .light)
yAxis.labelCount = 10
yAxis.axisMinimum = 0
yAxis.axisMaximum = 80
yAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
```

and below is picture, and as we can see, the range reaches 100
[the picture for radar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAaPf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the demo and messed around with the library for radar charts. The following gets you a max y axis of 80.

```
let yAxis = chartView.yAxis
yAxis.labelFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 9, weight: .light)
yAxis.labelCount = 6
yAxis.axisMinimum = 0
yAxis.axisMaximum = 60
yAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
```

I'll do more digging when I get home to see why the axisMaximum is behaving so erratically.

[image]

Comment: Why its not straight forward?